# Find rows of a matrix whose certain columns all match a condition

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix with many rows and columns, for example a small subset would be:

```
1     2     3     4     5     6
1     1     5     6     0     0
1     2     2     3     2     1
1     2     0     3     4     5
1     9     5     7     3     0
```

I want to find the rows whose columns #4, #5 and #6 contain elements greater than zero, so I in this case would get a vector like this:

```
 1
 3
 4
```

I have tried using the find() function this way:

```
idx = find(y(:, 4:6) > 0)
```

but I get this:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 8
 9
10
11
13
14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `find` and `all` like this:

```
idx = find(all(y(:,4:6) > 0, 2))
```

This gives:

```
>> y = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 1 1 5 6 0 0; 1 2 2 3 2 1; 1 2 0 3 4 5; 1 9 5 7 3 0]
y =

   1   2   3   4   5   6
   1   1   5   6   0   0
   1   2   2   3   2   1
   1   2   0   3   4   5
   1   9   5   7   3   0

>> idx = find(all(y(:,4:6) > 0, 2))
idx =

   1
   3
   4
```

The idea is that we extract columns 4 to 6, check which values are greater than 0, operate along the 2nd dimension with an AND condition (`all`), and then extract which indices (rows) are 1/true in the resulting column vector.

Comment: You can even get rid of `> 0`, since `all` already do that. `idx = find(all(y(:,4:6) , 2))` will do just fine.

Comment: Not quite: `all()` does `!= 0` NOT `> 0`. This makes a difference if you potentially have negative values in your data.